# IIS cannot connect to SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I have read the other questions like this on stack overflow and MSDN but still cannot find the answer to this problem.

My dev machine is running VS2010SP1 and IIS7. IIS7 was installed after .Net framework, so I have had to configure the website manually. I'm deploying the application to IIS locally rather than using Casinni.

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2010 on Win7 64bit (dev machine)
- IIS running on Win7 64bit (dev machine)
- SQL Server 2008 running on Win2008 (server)

In the options for the website in Visual Studio, I select use IIS and click Create Virtual Directory, which works (ie. it creates the directory successfully).

But when I then run the application I get a SQL Connection error saying:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a coneection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections and I CAN connect from the dev machine to SQL Server in Management Studio using the same credentials (currently the sa account and yes I know that's bad and will be changing it later, this is only for dev purposes).

I tried changing the `machine.config` file for the entry `LocalSqlServer` to point to the server just in case, but that didn't help even though the server is remote and not local.

I also tried adding this to the web.config:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
     connectionString="Data Source=esdc01;Initial Catalog=ECS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Network Library=dbnmpntw;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The connection string in `web.config` is correct.

If I go into the properties of the web site in VS2010 and change it back to "Use Visual Studio Development Server" then the application works fine and it DOES connect to SQL Server.

So it seems when I use IIS, the `web.config` NOR the `machine.config` are accessed for their connection strings... so where is IIS looking for the connection string? I'm baffled!

On the server, both Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled.

Comment: FYI if I replace the servername esdc01 with the server IP address, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You said that Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled on the server.

Try removing the "Network Library=dbnmpntw" element.  If that doesn't work, try changing it to "Network Library=dbmssocn" and see if it will connect using TCP/IP.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both and neither work. They also don't work if I am just using Casinni dev server and not IIS, whereas at least using the dbnmpntw setting does work with Casinni.